# how to access value form array

Tags: php, arrays

please find below contains array in php

```
    $data = array ( 'questions' => array ( 1 => 
array (
  'section_id' => '61',
  'questionid' => '2035',
  'time_spent' => '0',
),
2 => 
array (
  'section_id' => '61',
  'questionid' => '2036',
  'time_spent' => '0',
),
3 => 
array (
  'section_id' => '61',
  'questionid' => '2037',
  'time_spent' => '0',
),
 ),)
```

how can i access section_id, and time_spent data from array

Comment: Using foreach or for loop

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please use the below code : Also see this [link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

```
foreach($data as $key => $values){
    foreach ($values as $ikey => $secArr) {
        # code...
        $section_id = $secArr['section_id'];
        $time_spent = $secArr['time_spent'];

        echo 'Section Id: '.$section_id.' | Time Spend:'.$time_spent.'</br>';
    }
}
```

I hope it will helps you.